# What is the difference between a guilt offering and a sin offering?

Tags: law, moses, offering

I’m reading Leviticus and I know that there are 5 types of offerings:

1. Burnt offering.
2. Grain offering.
3. Fellowship offering.
4. Sin offering.
5. Guilt offering.

But I’m having problems seeing the difference between the sin offering and the guilt offering. Both have unintentional offerings, and are made for sins against God and people. The only real difference that I’ve seen is that restitution is made for the guilt offering. Please help me understand this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone in struggling with this question. The ancient and medieval rabbis debated the issues you mention. In  very general terms, sin offerings usually involved mere ritual impurity or unintentional sins. Guilt offerings were more likely to involve conscious violations of the Law. But this is just a rule of thumb.

Since the Temple no longer exists, the question has never been completely clarified, because - in practical terms - it is moot. In modern times, an attempt has been made to understand the biblical data with reference to a) primitive traditions of the wilderness period, b) First Temple traditions, and c) regulations enacted after the Babylon exile (the Second Temple period). I addition, the prophets interpreted Guilt Offering spiritually, emphasizing that atonement is not merely a matter of blood sacrifice but of personal piety and repentance. I recommend the [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13764-sin-offering) articles on these subjects for a summary of the biblical data and scholarly analysis. The editors conclude:

> The sin-offering was an ancient sacrifice. In the later ritual it is
> associated with the Burnt Offering and the Guilt-Offering... A more
> advanced conception may be looked for in cases where the sin-offering
> is associated with atonement for the nation... It is clear that the
> sin-offering was not primarily an offering for real sins, but for the
> unconscious violation of mere taboos. It was demanded in the case of
> actual sins only sporadically, and then only to a slight degree.

The prophets and the later priestly compilers of the Hebrew scriptures used the term "kofer" (ransom) in relation to the [guilt offering](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6934-guilt-offering). Often identified with atonement, this offering was associated with sins that were committed consciously. The later prophets and psalmists often spoke of guilt offerings of animals being replaced by "mercy not sacrifice" (Hos. 6:6) and the "bullocks of our lips" (Hos 14:3).

Micah 6:6-8

> Shall I come before him with burnt offerings, with calves of a year
> old? . . . Shall I give my first-born for my transgression, the fruit
> of my body for the sin of my soul? He hath shewed thee, O man, what is
> good; and what doth the Lord require of thee but to do justly, and to
> love mercy, and to walk humbly with thy God?

**Conclusion**: Guilt offerings and sin offerings overlap. Modern scholars tend to see the guilt offering as a later development. In time, guilt offerings came to be associated with conscious sins and the idea of atonement.

Comment: I'm reading a study book on Hosea & Micah and the author makes the point: "Transgressions or rebellion refers to positive acts that are contrary to the Lord's requirements and in defiance of his authority. The connotation of 'sins' is more negative, indicating rather failure, default, not matching up to the standards of God's law." I take that to mean transgression/rebellion is far more serious in the O.T., being positively decided to do. Would you say that's why Isaiah 53:7-8 says Messiah was wounded for our transgressions, stricken for the transgressions of God's people?

Comment: I found out the answer but thank you for trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

We may never completely understand the distinctions in the categories of the Old Testament concerning “sin” and “guilt” as mentioned in the Old Testament. Perhaps God wanted to keep them sharp minded and aware and engaged and this was His way of keeping them engaged- having a requirement of the details of the different laws that they had to think about and remember.  It was a not super easy as bringing one type of animal and one procedure for all offenses.
We Christians lump together both sin and the associated guilt. I think that is what God wants us to do in our time now, to see it all as a picture that needs redemption.  It seems that Paul and the other writers of the New Testament want us to see it that way too because they highlight the grace of God coming through Christ who is the perfect, blameless sacrifice for sin. (Isaiah 53, John 1:29)  The apostles writing is detailed and engages us in good ways as we ponder what they say and the truths they convey.  The truths God gave them to write helps form our hearts as worshippers just as His laws properly formed the hearts of the Old Testament priests and citizens in ancient Israel.  That was the intention and if any particular priest understood the laws that way he taught the message clearly- you are a sinner, we all are sinners and we need the miraculous and blessed work of God to forgive our sin.   All sin has some guilt associated with it because all sin affects the sinner in some way.  All sin taints us in regard to being with God. (Psalm 51:4) But we shouldn’t let this inability to decipher a difference of sin and guilt bother us as we read Leviticus.  God wanted the Old testament follower of Him to know all sin has ramifications and consequences.  There is a tangible cost in being made right with God.  Everything about this fallen word and our living here in his world needs to be redeemed. (Genesis 2, Romans 3:23) God has sent His son Jesus to redeem us and in time He will make all things right. (John 3:16) That is the important point He was giving a blessing to the Old Testament Hebrew that others outside of the Hebrews could not receive.  Then in the time of Christ He told the apostles that he would be delivering this atonement to all people.(1 John 1:9)  The teaching of sins against God had been established and the fulfillment of the forgiveness of sins by God had been fully completed in Christ.  That is the good news gospel, as Jesus said, “It is Finished.” (John 19:30)  For this we can say, “Praise the Lord” just as the Old Testament  Hebrew worshippers said in their own Hebrew words as they worshipped God thanking God as He worked in their time.
We Christians can ask God to forgive us over and over but there is no crime or offense to God if we don’t because in our hearts we thank Him over and over for His grace through Christ and the forgiveness of our sins.  Just as their system of sacrifice was never ending, so too is our thankfulness never ending because we, as they, continue to live in a sin-filled world and get caught in sins.  Instead of offering animal sacrifices we think of the price Jesus paid for us. This directive given them by God was a distinction between the God-fearing Jews of the Old Testament and the pagans. Our directive via the truths of the New Testament continues to be a distinction between Christians and other false religions. (John 14:6)
It is said that forever in heaven Christ will show His scars.  We don’t know for sure and we don’t want to assume this is the case but the inhabitants in heaven are there understanding what He has done and are thankful for His work.  In their souls is the reflection of the cross as though they wear a mirror, not literally but internally, and see that cross on which the son of God gave Himself for each of them ever and always.  This separates us from Him, we cannot save ourselves (Ephesians 2:8,9) but by His grace He has given His life for us.  Greater love has no one than he lay His life down for his friends. (John 15:13) In the most perfect and glorious sense God has done this, laid down His life for us; we cannot fathom this completely because God is perfect and we are not.  But we can understand it as a great love as He, the great shepherd and Father, compassionately desires His children to be reconciled to Him. That is the beauty of the gospel- God’s amazing love and this is what He wants us to learn from all of this both Old Testament and New.  This is just a tiny thumbnail sketch, a brief overview of some of the important teachings of the Bible in Leviticus but may help if people are stuck understanding the picture of some chapters in Leviticus.  Reading through Leviticus you get an idea of the labor intensive works they did in faith to God.  It takes a significant amount of time to prepare a whole large animal and even a  smaller one and make it ready as an offering to God.  All the time they are preparing it and cooking or burning it they would be and should be thinking about their sin and God’s good work of redemption. God wants us to read his word and think about it, there really is no substitute for this because He can and will interact with the person as we humans read through the entire Bible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).